# How to use Julius on 11.10

Tags: speech-recognition

I like to set a speech recognition on my laptop and I try julius but I have no idea how to use it.

Can any body help or point me on the right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since Lucid you can install it from Ubuntu Software Center. You can find it here on-line: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/julius-voxforge/

If needed you can also use the binary package. `julius-4.2.1-linuxbin.tar.gz` as an example.

```
http://jaist.dl.sourceforge.jp/julius-4.2.1-linuxbin.tar.gz
tar xvf julius-4.2.1-linuxbin.tar.gz && cd julius-4.2.1-linuxbin/ &&
sudo ./run_install.sh
```

You might need to install `libx11` too and can install the prior to the install.sh script with:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```